# Match text up to given character but excluding character occurrence within single quotes in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to extract text from a string up to the next occurrence of a `/`, not counting slashes that occur within single quotes. For example

```
my $str="test 'a/b' c/ xxx /";
$str =~ /(.*?)\//;
print "$1\n";
```

gives

```
test 'a
```

whereas I would like to get:

```
test 'a/b' c
```

Comment: Is it possible for the single quotes to enclose other escaped single quotes?  'foo\'bar' ?

Comment: @Miller No that is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this:

```
$str =~ /^((?>[^'\/]+|'[^']*')*)\//;
```

Comment: Why possessiveness, what can go wrong with just `(?:[^'\/]+|'[^']*')+\/`?

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work perfectly. It would be nice with a short explanation though..

Comment: @raina77ow: because if the string doesn't contain slashes, the pattern will become a good candidat for catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: Shouldn't there be `^` at the beginning? Otherwise this'll match `a/` if all the other slashes are not there.

Comment: @raina77ow: You are right, I will change the quantifier too.

Answer (score 4):

[`Text::ParseWords`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aParseWords) can handle quoted delimiters:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::ParseWords;

my $str = "test 'a/b' c/ xxx /";
my ($first) = quotewords('/', 1, $str);
print $first;
```

**Output:**

```
test 'a/b' c
```

Comment: Its a very useful module, and also part of the core.

Answer (score 3):

```
my $str="test 'a/b' c/ xxx /";

$str =~ m{^((?>[^'/]+|'[^']*')*)/};

print $1;
```

Or if strings can contain escaped single quotes:

```
$str =~ m{^((?>[^'/]+|'(?>[^'\\]+|\\.)*')*)/}x;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me empty output.

Comment: Note the 'x' modifier.  Can just remove the spacing.

Answer (score 0):

If your string data is always "A/B/" then you could use the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $str = "test 'a/b' c/ xxx /";
$str =~ m/(.*)\/(.*)\/$/;
print "$1\n";
```